Remove all characters between two sets of strings, the first being a name-pair (Python-Pandas)
I have a column in pandas structed as below:
John Doe\n \n\n \n\n \nBlack    
Jane Doe\r\n\n \r\n\n \r\n\n \r\nViolet

All the relevant unnecessary string blocks start with a '\' immediately after the name-pair and end with an '\n'.
I want this to be split into two columns consisting of the name-pair and the latter string, like so:



Column A
Column B




John Doe
Black


Jane Doe
Violet



Any leads much appreciated.
I tried df['column'].str.replace('\(.*$', ''), but this gives an error
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

This question is similar to: How can I put an actual backslash in a string literal (not use it for an escape sequence)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

To make it more clear, your search string in your replace() method, '\(.*$', has a backslash in it, which is an escape character in python string literals. Using a raw-string, by adding an r in front of the string literal, will make the backslash behave like a regular character: r'\(.*$' and your code will likely work. raw-strings are commonly used when defining regex patterns and windows file paths.

I don't see how that code would cause an unterminated literal.  Please edit the question and post the full error traceback message.

I guess you want to such that. If you need, it can developed regex pattern according to need.
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Unproccesed_data': ['John Doe\n \n\n \n\n \nBlack', 'Jane Doe\r\n\n \r\n\n \r\n\n \r\nViolet']})
df['Name'],df['Last_Name'] = df.Unproccesed_data.str.split('[\\n\\r]\s+')

